# Problem with Authentication

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

My web config, which is a config file in a folder (a config file additional to the main config file in the virtual directory):

```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".MyCookie" loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx"   protection="All" timeout="43200" path="/">
          <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
            <user name="user" password="ca064d0730abfeb09e383a0e82e65f73"/>
          </credentials>
        </forms>
      </authentication>

      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Moderator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>



    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The error that I get:

> Error 3   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.      5

I am trying to redirect any anonymous users from the administrator and moderator directories.. so I want any anonymous user or users with no role to be redirected to register.aspx..but i dont get it to work because I get that error and I dont know why!! :(

Comment: I am assuming you have a copy post error above?  First line first character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `authentication` tag **is not permited on subdirectories web.config,** unless you define this subdirectory as a full asp.net application, means a diferent aplication than the root - I not suggest it.

so remove this, and keep it to the root web.config only.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">... </authentication>
```

Comment: but then it makes problems....how can I tell the thingy to deliver the user to teh Register page..?

Comment: @Matrix001 You do not have no other solution than to use the code behind to handle the differentiation of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your sub directory as location in your web.config.

Check [location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Also check [this scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815174).

[This article](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/content/FormAuthentication/FormAuthentication.html) explains how to organize your web.configs and location elements.

> This is because the  section is only supported in IIS
>   application directories, which doesn't include subdirectories of an
>   IIS application.

Comment: Just like this:   <location path="~/Administrator">